# Why doesn't an atom reemit the photons it absorbs?

Tags: photons, atomic-physics

When light falls on an atom and the energy of the photons matches the gap between the energy levels of electrons of this atom, the electrons will absorb the photons to get excited to the higher energy level. This makes different things have different  colors. My question is - why don't these electrons fall back to their original energy levels, reemitting the absorbed photons?

Comment: They do; for every absorption spectrum, there is a corresponding emission spectrum. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_spectrum) for more information. Since you are new to the site, please also note that questions (such as this one) that can be answered through a quick internet search will not receive a great response; a little research will help you to move past general lack of information and pinpoint any more nuanced misunderstanding you might have, which is what this site is better suited to help with.

Answer (score 5):

Who says that they don't? It's called [spontaneous emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission) (sometimes also [fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence) or [phosphorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence)) and it is a key part of atomic physics. For more details, see any introductory textbook on quantum physics.